# xhr ajax restart after abort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a http long polling polling done like this:

```
   xhr = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/pubsub.php",
        ...
```

Ajax returns a xhr object. And I use it in another function to abort the long polling request by doing xhr.abort();

After I do this, how can I restart the long polling request? Is there a method to restart?

Thanks

Comment: you can put this ajax in one function and call it again

Comment: "*Is there a method to restart?*" No, just send another like any other request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API present to restart the AJAX, But you can simulate the restart of AJAX by calling the AJAX again in `error` callback function.

```js
var xhr;

function callAJAX() {
    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/dummyURL",
        error: function (xhr, e) {
            console.log("Error Occured " + e);
            callAJAX(); // Restart the AJAX call
        }
    })
}

callAJAX();


xhr.abort()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing in my projects,

If I see a long delay in the ajax response, I simply abort the previous ajax request and make a new request in the same method as shown below,

Note: I don't call the GetData() mmethod in any loop, rather it is a button click action (say refresh) from application user.

```
function GetData()
{
            if (getDataAjaxCall && getDataAjaxCall.readyState != 4)
                getDataAjaxCall.abort();

               var searchRequest = {};
               searchRequest.Criteria = []; //set some criteria    

    getDataAjaxCall = $.ajax({
                url: 'api/DataController/GetData',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: searchRequest,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                   //do tasks you want on success
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    if (textStatus != 'abort') {
                        //display error message on actual error
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I hope the above lines of code might give you some idea.

Also, in the error callback, place a check to catch the abort and handle it separately.

Comment: do not blindly edit  answers, you said in comments that no result is showing, are you aware of `console.log()` function.